# How to declare date format style in model when `[DataType(DataType.Text)]` is used

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-datepicker

Typically, when I use the `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:d}")]` attribute with a DateTime property in my model, the DateTime values correctly show only the date part only.

However, because Edge (and only Edge) overrides the Bootstrap Datepicker to show its own Datepicker, I have to change my attributes to the following (showing one property in my model as an example):

> ```
> [Required]
> [Display(Name="Start Date")]
> [DataType(DataType.Text)]  // this is required to make Bootstrap 
>                            // datepicker work with Edge
> [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:d}")] // this attribute is now ignored
> public DateTime? SelectedStartDate { get; set; }
> ```

In other words, I have to declare the DateTime field as text, and so when my page is rendered, it looks like this.

[image: Value is rendered as DateTime instead of time]

When the user selects a date, the correct format is shown, so that part is nailed down.

> ```
> <script>
>   $(function () {
>       var formatparam = {format:"mm/dd/yyyy", setDate: new Date(), autoclose: true };
>       $("#SelectedStartDate").datepicker(formatparam);
>       $("#SelectedEndDate").datepicker(formatparam);
>   });
> </script>
> ```

Is there something I can declare in the model or in the script block so that the default value appears as Date only and not as DateTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through several paradigm shifts and refactoring. Thanks to @Steven Muecke for his suggestion.

In earlier iterations, I had tried `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedStartDate)` without success. What I didn't know was that I also needed to add the formatting string, so it looks like this:

> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedStartDate, "{0:d}")

So my Model is cleaner:

> ```
> [Required]
> [Display(Name="Start Date")] 
> [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:d}")]
> public DateTime? SelectedStartDate { get; set; }
> ```

The behavior is now what I need it to be: the default view is formatted as a Date only and not DateTime.

Comment: You should never use a `string` for a `DateTime` property. Just generate the view using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedStartDate, "{0:d}")`. Or if you want to use `EditorFor()`, then the attribute needs to be `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

Comment: I had tried TextBoxFor, but I didn't know about needing to use the format string in the helper: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedStartDate, "{0:d}")`. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Given that SelectedStartDate will be string

```
@string.Format("{0:d}", Model.SelectedStartDate)
```

Comment: In my Razor code, I have `Start Date @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SelectedStartDate)`. How would I apply that?

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SelectedStartDate, new { @Value = string.Format("{0:d}", m.SelectedStartDate))` may work... Haven't tested, but it should.

Comment: I realized that I needed a paradigm shift. Answered my own question by refactoring my code.